# Дерево решений (Decision Tree) или случайный лес (Random Forest)?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

порой деревья решений справляются с задачей лучше , чем целый лес. Относительно плохой результат леса связан с обобщением ответов всех деревьев леса?
Правильно ли предположение , что на больших данных лес будет лучше , чем одно дерево ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опытные люди утверждают, что одиночные деревья (`Decision Tree`) более подвержены проблеме переобучения (`overfitting`), по сравнению со случайным лесом (`Random Forest`).

Проблемы переобучения особенно заметны на больших наборах данных, поэтому, скорее всего, на больших наборах данных, случайный лес будет лучше справляться с незнакомыми данными.

Comment: я не понимаю , при чём тут переобучение , если я использовал cross_val_score